# Merge gives an empty output

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.3, merge

Within ModelBuilder I've got an orginal file, out of this file a few locations are extracted by mask and the data has been changed afterward. Now I am trying to put this data back by first erasing the mask locations in the orginal file, and then merging this with the changed data.

This is supposed to paste it back into place, and the geometry does...but the data gets created as an empty output. I have no idea what is going wrong!

I've added my model as extra information.

My goal with this is to then delete all the features within the orginal file and append the features from this file. Therefor updating the orginal file without overwriting or deleting it.

Running: Arcgis 10.3.1

[image: Model]

Comment: Why do you need the iterator? One Erase and merge should be enough.

Comment: Because the user of the tool may choose for multiple layers at once. And I want to give them that option rather than having to start the tool over and over again (They work a lot in batch)

Comment: I am using the Iterate Feature Classes, the box wasn't big enough to show it, I do apologize for that!

Comment: Feed the output of erase into a collects value tool, that becomes a sub-model in a model with just a merge tool. Don't know what a sub-model is, then read the help file.